# Saving file to local application data and selecting it using xamarin essentials file picker

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, file-handling

Im using the Xamarin Essentials file picker to allow a user to select a file that has been created by the application.
I can get the path using

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
```

And save the file there, but I cant find the folder using the file picker. As far as I understand it Android wont let you access these Application folders yourself, is that correct?

Hard coding a file path works and allows me to select the file using the file picker but I need a solution without hard coding that works on both Android and iOS. All of the Environment.SpecialFolder paths point to locations that I cant find through the file picker.

Comment: Application files do indeed have restricted access under Android. They are not publicly accessible and are removed along with the application on uninstall. Ideally, they should be used for local database or configuration. I thought that some of the Xamarin.Essentials file definitions were accessible publicly. In any case, you can always have a hard coded path defined for each OS - just define it within the Android or iOS project. You could even get the user to select the location and store that as in your app configuration at runtime.

Comment: You cannot choose files from special folders in the file picker. You're trying to do something that the operating system actively prevents.